# Calling multiple times to write function but the text is out of order (python)

Tags: python, file

I have some issues with writing to a file using python.

```
new_lib_file = open("new_lib_file.lib", "w")
new_lib_file.write("11111\n")
new_lib_file.write("22222\n")
new_lib_file.close()
```

The file content is:

```
22222
11111
```

instead of:

```
11111
22222
```

What can be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the file is even being modified? Unless you have other code that binds `write` to something (which I'm not what that would be, as it does not accept a file descriptor), `write("11111\n")` should have generated an error. It should be `new_lib_file.write(...)`

Comment: This is not a reproducible error or problem.

Answer (score 1):

You also try open the using `with` keyword to write on it

```
with open("new_lib_file.lib", "w") as f:
    f.write("11111\n")
    f.write("22222\n")
```

output

```
11111
22222
```

Comment: No need to use `.close` if using `with`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_lib_file = open("new_lib_file.lib", "w")
new_lib_file.write("11111\n")
new_lib_file.write("22222\n")
new_lib_file.close()
```

Content of the file will be:

```
11111
22222
```

Comment: I was confused and my original code call to write with . and not as I mentioned: 'file = write()'.

Comment: Actually, your code would not run, because Python did not know what is `write` method. My code above is just predefined writing method for file objects in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use equals operator, instead you need to do this `new_lib_file.write('your line')`

And also, If you are thinking not to overwrite your file, use append. `a` instead of `w`. Like so:

```
new_lib_file = open("new_lib_file.lib", "a")
new_lib_file.write("11111\n")
new_lib_file.write("22222\n")
new_lib_file.close()
```

or

```
with open('new_lib_file.lib', "w") as f:
  f.write('11111\n')
  f.write('22222\n')
```

Comment: The first example will work in different way does an OP want

Comment: I was confused and my original code call to write with . and not as I mentioned: 'file = write()'.